# Python Static Class attributes

Tags: python

Is it possible in Python make a static attribute of class which will be same for all instances (objects) of that class, they all will use same reference to that attribute without creating their own attributes.

For example :

```
class myClass:
    __a = 0

    def __init__(self, b, c):
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def increase_A(self):
        self.__a += 1
        return

    def get_A(self):
        return self.__a
```

So if I have

```
myObject1 = myClass(1,2)
myObject2 = myClass(3,4)

myObject2.increase_A()

print myObject1.get_A()
```

will show **one** and not **zero**, couse they share the same variable ?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your code work as it appears you intend, use `myClass.__a` to access the variable, instead of `self.__a`.

```
def increase_A(self):
    myClass.__a += 1
    return

def get_A(self):
    return myClass.__a
```

Answer (score 3):

They start off as the same variable. However, when you do

```
self.__a += 1
```

this rebinds the object's `__a` to a new object whose value is `1`.

It does not change any other object's `__a` so the code will print out `0`.